# Java & Order of Execution

Tags: java, android, execution

I released my first Android app and I'm attempting to troubleshoot some bugs that have resulted in crashes (as identified via the Google Play Console).

The code simplified the code as much as possible - the following method is called:

```
private void gameMethod(int switchCase, ArrayList gameArray) {


boolean magicBoolean = false;
ArrayList magicList = new ArrayList<>();

switch(switchCase) {
    case 1:
          for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   
              if(gameArray.get(i) == 2) {
         
                  magicBoolean = true;
              } 

              if(magicBoolean) {
                  magicList.add(gameArray.get(i));
              } 
           }
           break;

     case 2:
          // basic repeat of case 1
          break;
     case 3:
          // basic repeat of case 1
          break;
                                                        
}


newMagicMethod(ArrayList magicList);
```

As you can see, the 2nd method (newMagicMethod) uses the magicList which is populated via the switch. The magicList size will never be 0, the first method is only called when the array has more than 1 item in it.

In my crash report it is telling me the following:

**Exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0**

So I conclude that somehow the 2nd method is attempting to use the magicList (e.g find and use the 1st item on the list) and then crashes when the list is empty.

My question would be is there any way that the Java code would attempt to execute the call to the newMagicMethod() FIRST before the switch statement is executed. Obviously is this is the case this would explain how the arrayList could be empty and would cause a crash. Otherwise I have look for other reasons as to why the arrayList could be empty.

If I could confirm if code like this can execute out of order, I would figure out a way to resolve/define the order.

Comment: What's `I` in your `for` loop? Might that be a typo and it should actually be `i`? You're also missing an delcaration/ initialization for `array`.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Thanks, I updated the example to address the array and fix the I typo.

Comment: That code is really incomplete and full of syntax errors it's really hard to understand. What you show couldn't produce a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` unless there are threads that modified `array` or maybe `magicList`. The exception you get should also include a line where it happened, that would very useful to know.

Comment: Also `case` is a reserved keyword which you cannot use as a variable/ parameter name.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the feedback. I tried to simply it and maybe made the code more confusing. And yes even with the simplification I made some errors. Hopefully the revised example is easier to understand. In the Google Play Console it doesn't provide with a line where the crash happened - as far as I know that only applies in Android Studio's Logcat.

Comment: if you have hardcoded `i < 4` then yes, that code would always crash if `gameArray`  is not at least 4 long, in that code it's not changed from it's initial empty state from `new ArrayList<>()` at all before it hits that for loop. (in the version before it couldn't crash because you used .length()). Not sure what your actual code really does, but don't simplify the code to the point where it no longer correctly represents your actual code. Maybe post it as is and just replace irrelevant parts with comments. Java won't skip over code, it goes step by step through your code so that isn't it

Comment: correction, `magicList` is empty, `gameArray` is whatever you pass in the method. `gameArray` still needs to be 4 long or ` gameArray.get(i)` fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is NO — the `switch` statement itself is not asynchronous. It will be fully executed, and only after that will your `newMagicMethod()` be called.

However, it seems that the code you provided is pseudo-code, since it wouldn't compile. For example, you can't declare an ArrayList inline within a method call, as you currently do here, where you presumably meant to use the `magicList` variable declared further up within `gameMethod()`:

```
newMagicMethod(ArrayList magicList)
```

Given that you've only provided pseudo-code, here are a couple of things to consider:

- Do you have any asynchronous calls in your `case` blocks? If so, you may have introduced a race condition where there's no guarantee that your collection will be populated before the call to `newMagicMethod()`.
- Are you sure the logic in your `case` blocks guarantees that at least one object will end up in your collection? The most likely explanation here is that you failed to account for a scenario whereby your calls to `add()` will be bypassed. You can use breakpoints or logging to catch such unexpected scenarios.
- Do you have a `default` block, where you log the fact that your collection will be empty, or maybe throw an exception? It's all-too-common for developers to assume they've covered all cases in a `switch` statement, when in fact there are one or more cases for which they forgot to account.

Comment: Thanks Mark for such a thorough answer. I'm still new at this so I'm learning to get better at posting my questions and showing better code. I do think I have any other asynchronous calls in the switch - only a for loop with 2 if statements inside. I don't think there are any cases where the collection will bypass the add. For this, there is no default block in the switch, it would serve no purpose. I'll continue to examine if there is any scenario where the collection could be zero - since that is the only option left as the source for the crash. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Keep in mind that a default block might not serve a purpose in the code as it exists today, but could highlight an unhandled scenario when code changes occur in the future. It's a best practice to log an error or throw an exception in a default block that you expect never to be hit. I refer to these as design-time exceptions.